# Node-inspector is ignoring my bin folder entirely

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mocha.js, node-inspector

I'm trying to debug my REST-API unit tests (mocha) with node-inspector, and I need to set a breakpoint inside of a file that is located within a folder called "bin" inside of my project, however, node-inspector is either completely ignoring it or not recognizing it for some reason. Some screenshots for comparison:

1) My code editor's file tree (the correct one) -

[image: editorcomparison]

2) The node-inspector's file tree -

[image: nodecomparison]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What command are you using to start your application along with `node-inspector`? Is `bin/www` being executed as part of the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went ahead and renamed the folder to 'server' or something perhaps more arbitrary than 'bin', but I'm quite sure that more importantly I added a ".js" extension to the file 'www'. That worked for me. Perhaps node-inspector solely looks for javascript files in the given directory.

Comment: Yes, the extension `.js` is important.